# Submit form of iframe which is in different domain from parent window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain, postmessage

I need to submit a form which is loaded inside a iframe.

But this src will be loaded from different domain from its parent page.

I have tried Window.postMessage which can communicate to inner iframe but I doubt for cross domain page also for which we cant have to source control we can't add listener to that page.

So, Any help on this for iframe cross browser site communication without any code added on the iframe page.

Comment: Do you have control over the content of the page hosted in the iframe?

Comment: @Nathan I dont have control on the content, since its a third party page.